# iOS data sharing to Google Apps for social features: Workable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-app-engine

I'm putting on my thinking cap for this one, looking for a **high level overview of possibility**.  I'm the author of an iPhone app that tracks user generated statistics.  Data is essentially stored in a table on the device, with each entry having several fields/columns.  Users can then sort that data, view graphs, and do other nerdy number crunching stuff.  I want to take it farther and incorporate a sharing platform online.  Game Center, Open Feint and other third party platforms are too narrow in scope.  I'm interested in writing a web app, that users can visit to do three things:

1. Post New Table entries (automated by device)
2. View own entries and share via web (read only)
3. View other members table entries (read only)

Is Google App Engine a viable solution for this?  My iOS app will require a POST URL, and the web app will need to save that authenticated user's data, and possibly return an "identifier" value to be referenced in the future in case the user needs to modify the item on the web.  It will also require a GET URL to retrieve the authenticated user's statistics one by one or in total.

Next, the user will be able to visit the website and type in a "username" (probably email address) and see read-only statistics that have been submitted.

Thank you in advance for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could do all that with App Engine. If you wanted to, you could even make that local table of data sync with your app on GAE.

Really, there's not much on GAE that you can't do, although sometimes the database layer take some time to get used to.

My personal preference would be to set up a Django instance, but you could use any Python or Java-based app, depending on what you're comfortable with.

In short, yeah, you won't have any trouble doing basic REST work with GAE, and you could probably push it harder to do some more number crunching on those stats.